# EventListener like AbstractMongoEventListener in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb

We are migrating from a Spring Data MongoDB repository to a Spring Data JPA repository. We were using the AbstractMongoEventListener to capture `onBeforeConvert` and `onAfterLoad` events to enhance the data objects before returning them from our Service layer.

I cannot find similar EventListeners in Spring Data JPA. Are there hooks in Spring Data JPA that I can use to do the same thing? It would be great if I can avoid modifying our service layer to make this change from MongoDB to JPA.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@PrePersist` annotation is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Where did you put this annotation ? Can you share sample code ?

Comment: This article has good description and examples - https://www.concretepage.com/java/jpa/jpa-entitylisteners-example-with-callbacks-prepersist-postpersist-postload-preupdate-postupdate-preremove-postremove